# ExpandableListView open collapse problem

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using a custom expandable list adapter. I highlight a child when the user clicks on it. This works fine until the user opens/collapses a group. Say the user touches Group 2 Item 1. This highlights Group 2 Item 1. Then the user opens Group 1. Now Group 3 Item 2 is highlighted. I have done some testing choosing different items and I can not find a pattern where the highlighted row will jump to. Sometimes its up in the list, sometimes its down. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic to put in my activity's `onGroupExpandListener` and `onGroupCollapseListener` to rehighlight the correct view. Any ideas?

EDIT: Current code inside my onChildClickListener

```
if (groupPosition == 0){ 
      switch(childPosition) {
      case 0: 
        previouslySelectedView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
        currentlySelectedView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue); 
        break;
```

Same code for all the groups/children

Comment: Post your code so we can see if you're doing something that might cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item slection in ExpandableListView is made through flat list (absolute positiond). Thus if the newlly opened group is before the currenet selection and has fewer children then the selection will move up and vice versa. I suggest to set choice mode to none and implement onclick/expand logic to handle focus on your own - implement tags for views, for example, and set the currently highlighted item via the tag.

Here are few suggestions:

1. In the ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener first you perform ExpandableListView.findViewWithTag(theTag) to check for views with such tag and unmark them (also setTag(null)) and restore the background. Then for the item clicked setTag(theTag) and change the background to selected. Of course you can have some other logic and have multiple items marked. Note that once the view is destroyed you will lose the selection (for example during expands).
2. Have some custom map or something that will hold a unique ID of the view and the (un)marked state. That's the best solution that will allow to maintain persistent selection across scrolls and expands.
3. In the backing adapter introduce a "marked" state. Thus the marking will be persistent even between application start/stop. Not a good approach, though, because selection is more of a UI behaviour.

I am currently doing an ExpandableListView selection with Choice Mode Multiple of the list. But since, as I said, the selection is per position I had to sacrifice in terms of functionality - namely, I clear the selection whenever a manipulation is made. The previous implementation was with custom Map holding the selected IDs and - to honest - it was the better approach.

This is how I get selected IDs (remember I use choice mode multiple):

```
final SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = expList.getCheckedItemPositions();
final ExpandableListAdapter adapter = expList.getExpandableListAdapter();
List<Long> checkedIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
if (packedPositionType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
    for (int i = checkedPositions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (checkedPositions.valueAt(i)) {
            checkedIds.add(adapter.getGroupId(checkedPositions.keyAt(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, though, you will want to check for CHILD packed positions. Also note that my adapter has stable (unique) ids. If you do not have stable IDs then you can rely on ExpandableListView's getPackedPositionForChild() method and store the packed position as marked.

Comment: I did some research on tags. Looks like it could be a solution, but how do I give a listview item a tag programatically?

Comment: how do I get the unique id for view that was clicked? Is it a variable that is part of the view? Also once I store that id, I dont see how I can refer back to the view. sudo code would be like `View v = findViewWithUniqueID(uniqueID)` ?

Comment: The unique ID can be wither set by the adapter as a tag or you can use the formentioned packed positions which are basically the expandable list view variant of list view positions

Answer (score 2):

Right way to do it (Will solve jumping highlight upon group collapse)

Do the following on ExpandableListView:

**Step 1.** Set choice mode to single (Can be done in xml as **android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"**)

**Step 2.** Use a selector xml as background (**android:listSelector = "@drawable/selector_list_item"**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

**Step 3.** Call **expandableListView.setItemChecked(index,true)** in onChildClick() callback.

**index** is a 0 based index of the child item calculated as follows

**Group 1**   [index = 0]

- Child item 1
- Child item 2
- Child item 3  [index = 3]

**Group 2**  [index = 4]

- Child item 1
- Child item 2
- Child item 3  [index = 7]

**Group 3** [index = 8]

- Child item 1
- Child item 2
- Child item 3 [index = 11]

If we have list headers as well, they would also account for index values.

Here is a working example:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    ...

    int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
    parent.setItemChecked(index, true);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: This works, however the selection is lost when the group which contains the selected item is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the collapse issue :

```
mDrawerExpandableList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        if(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(selectedFragmentId) == groupPosition) {
            mDrawerExpandableList.setItemChecked(mDrawerExpandableList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition)), true);
        }
    }
});
mDrawerExpandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(selectedFragmentId) == groupPosition) {
            mDrawerExpandableList.setItemChecked(((ExpandableListView)drawerListView).getFlatListPosition(selectedFragmentId), true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//MY LIST A FOLLOWS



(0)SALES
    (0)SALES
    (1)SALES VIEW
    (2)SALES RETURN
    (3)SALES RETURN VIEW
(1)STOCK
    (0)ADD STOCK
    (1)VIEW STOCK
(2)SETTINGS
(3)NOTIFICATION



//declare tow integer variable globali as follows

private int lastCheckedGroupPosition=-1;
private int lastCheckedChildPosition=-1;


mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            if(groupPosition==2){
                lastCheckedGroupPosition=groupPosition;
                lastCheckedChildPosition=-1;
                int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition));
                parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

                //TODO Write here the code for opening settings page
                ...............
                ...............
                ...............
                return true;
            }
            else if(groupPosition==3){
                lastCheckedGroupPosition=groupPosition;
                lastCheckedChildPosition=-1;
                int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition));
                parent.setItemChecked(index, true);             

                //TODO Write here the code for opening settings page
                ...............
                ...............
                ...............

                return true;
            }
            return false;               
        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if(groupPosition==0){
                if(childPosition==0){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening SALES page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
                else if(childPosition==1){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening SALES VIEW page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
                else if(childPosition==2){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening SALES RETURN page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
                else if(childPosition==3){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening SALES RETURN VIEW page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
            }
            else if(groupPosition==1){
                if(childPosition==0){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening ADD STOCK page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
                else if(childPosition==1){
                    //TODO Write here the code for opening VIEW STOCK page
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    ...............                     
                }
            }
            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);
            lastCheckedGroupPosition=groupPosition;
            lastCheckedChildPosition=childPosition;
            return false;
        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition==lastCheckedGroupPosition){
                if(lastCheckedChildPosition!=-1){
                    int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(lastCheckedGroupPosition, lastCheckedChildPosition));
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                }
                else{
                    int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(lastCheckedGroupPosition));    
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                }
            }
            else{
                if(mDrawerList.isGroupExpanded(lastCheckedGroupPosition)){
                    if(lastCheckedChildPosition!=-1){
                        int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(lastCheckedGroupPosition, lastCheckedChildPosition));
                        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                    }
                    else{
                        int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(lastCheckedGroupPosition));    
                        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                    }
                }
                else{
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(-1, true);
                }
            }


        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

            if(groupPosition==lastCheckedGroupPosition){
                if(lastCheckedGroupPosition!=-1){
                    int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(lastCheckedGroupPosition));    
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);    
                }
                else{
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(-1, true);
                }
            }
            if(mDrawerList.isGroupExpanded(lastCheckedGroupPosition)){
                if(lastCheckedChildPosition!=-1){
                    int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(lastCheckedGroupPosition, lastCheckedChildPosition));
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                }
                else{
                    int index = mDrawerList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(lastCheckedGroupPosition));    
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(index, true);                            
                }
            }
            else{
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(-1, true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by recording the checked group position and child position in `checkedGroupPosition` and `checkedChildPosition`) and updating the checked item in `#onGroupExpand` and `#onGroupCollapse`:

```
override fun onGroupExpand(groupPosition: Int) {
    // Re-check the previous checked item because the flat position may have changed.
    updateCheckedItem()
  }

  override fun onGroupCollapse(groupPosition: Int) {
    // Re-check the previous checked item because the flat position may have changed.
    updateCheckedItem()
  }

  private fun updateCheckedItem() {
    // Checked item is a child item.
    if (checkedGroupPosition > -1 && checkedChildPosition > -1) {
      if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(checkedGroupPosition)) {
        // Check the item again if the group is expanded.
        expandableListView.setItemChecked(
          expandableListView.getFlatListPosition(
            ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(checkedGroupPosition, checkedChildPosition)
          ),
          true,
        )
      } else {
        // Clear the checked item if its group is collapsed.
        expandableListView.setItemChecked(-1, true)
      }
      return
    }
    // Checked item is a group item, check the item again.
    if (checkedGroupPosition > -1) {
      expandableListView.setItemChecked(
        expandableListView.getFlatListPosition(
          ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(checkedGroupPosition)
        ),
        true,
      )
    }
  }
```